# Remove list values based on series of other values

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a situation wherein a List object is built off of values pulled from a MSSQL database. However, this particular table is mysteriously getting an errant record or two tossed in. Removing the records cause trouble even though they have no referential links to any other tables, and will still get recreated without any known user actions taken. This causes some trouble as it puts unwanted values on display that add a little bit of confusion. The specific issue is that this is a platform that allows users to run a search for quotes, and the filtering allows for sales rep selection. The select/dropdown field is showing these errant values, and they need to be removed.

Given that deleting the offending table rows does not provide a desirable result, I was thinking that maybe the best course of action was to modify the code where the List object is created and either filter the values out or remove them after the object is populated. I'd like to do this in a clean, scalible fashion by providing some kind of appendable data object where I could just add in a new string value if something else cropped up as opposed to doing something clunky that adds new code to find the value and remove it each time.

My thought was to create a string array, and somehow loop through that to remove bad List values, but I wasn't entirely certain that was the best way to approach this, and I could not for the life of me think of a clean approach for this. I would think that the best way would be to add a filter within the Find arguments, but I don't know how to add in an array or list that way. Otherwise I figured to loop through the values either before or after the sorting of the List and remove any matches that way, but I wasn't sure that was the best choice of actions.

I have attached the current code, and would appreciate any suggestions.

```
int licenseeID = Helper.GetLicenseeIdByLicenseeShortName(Membership.ApplicationName);
List<User> listUsers;

if (Roles.IsUserInRole("Admin"))
{
    //get all users
    listUsers = User.Find(x => x.LicenseeID == licenseeID).ToList();
}
else
{
    //get only the current user
    listUsers = User.Find(x => (x.LicenseeID == licenseeID && x.EmailAddress == Membership.GetUser().Email)).ToList();
}
listUsers.Sort((x, y) => string.Compare(x.FirstName, y.FirstName));
```

**-- EDIT --**

I neglected to mention that I did not develop this, I merely inherited its maintenance after the original developer(s) disappeared, and my coworker who was assigned to it left the company. I'm not really really skilled at handling ASP.NET sites. Many object sources are hidden and unavailable for edit, I assume due to them being defined in a DLL somewhere. So, for any of these objects that are sourced from database tables, altering the tables will not help, since I would not be able to get the new data anyway.

However, I did try to do the following to filter out the undersirable data:

```
List<String> exclude = new List<String>(new String[] { "value1" , "value2" });
listUsers = User.Find(x => x.LicenseeID == licenseeID && !exclude.Contains(x.FirstName)).ToList();
```

Unfortunately it only resulted  in an error being displayed to the page.

**-- EDIT #2 --**

I got the server setup to accept a new event viewer source so I could write info to the Application log to see what was happening. Looks like this installation of ASP.NET does not accept "Contains" as an action on a List object. An error gets kicked out stating that the method is not available.

Comment: The best course of action would be to find out what is creating these records in the first place. Look for any code where you might be vulnerable to SQL injection, review any stored procedures or other sql actions, lock down write access to the database to only known sources, etc. I'm by no means a database expert, so I'm sure there are many other things you can do. Hiding the issue in the UI is probably the last thing to do, since no one will look at the problem once you do that.

Comment: another candidate for the extra record creation could be a trigger.

Comment: I did not create this, it's just been passed on over to me. I don't know enough about how this was engineered to even know where to find the cause of these couple of errant entries. They're not even properly correct, done in such a fashion that they're not likely added by users in any intentional fashion. And it's only the one table, which doesn't even handle access.

Answer (score 0):

I will probably add a bit to the table and flag Errant rows and then skip them when I query the table, something like

```
&& !ErrantData
```

Other way, that requires a bit more upkeep but doesn't require db change, would be to keep a text file that gets periodically updated and you read it and remove users from list based on it.

The bigger issue is unknown rows creeping in your database. Changing user credentials and adding creation timestamps may help you narrow down the search scope.

Comment: I would like to go that route, but honestly I can't even find what is actually pulling the data in the first place. I didn't create this, or develop it, I'm just being tasked with doing some repairs/maintenance for the simple reason that I have had experience programming in C#.

Comment: Yeah, the whole thing I need to alter is based off of this User object. I have not been able to locate the source of the class definition. I can do a lookup on the definition from within Visual Studio, but it looks like it is defined inside of some DLL somewhere. I can't modify the class to look at additional table columns.

Comment: All the best! Coding scars to reminisce over a few beers later in life.